# Element Disappears on iOS but not Webkit/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, sass

I have a flyout that includes a search form. When submitting this search form (it auto submits after the first three characters are entered into the form), the results briefly appear but then disappear. What is causing this?

[The live example of this is here](https://tohuw.net/about)

[The javascript triggering form submission](https://github.com/tohuw/tohuwnet-sources/blob/367c24a292d08c637c4c8913b8c82b19ba2dec13/_assets/javascripts/main.js#L30-L36)

[The SCSS involved](https://github.com/tohuw/tohuwnet-sources/blob/367c24a292d08c637c4c8913b8c82b19ba2dec13/_assets/stylesheets/_search.scss#L57-L75)

This is not a case of the z-index being mishandled for the cover; the background for the search results cover remains in place. Rather, the text itself disappears. I'm thinking this has something to do with the form resubmitting itself, but note that anything typed into the search form input is not visible after the first three characters, either.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following rule fixes this for me on the iOS Simulator on macOS:

```
.search, .site-nav {
  position: relative;
}
```

And adding this stretches the background to the height of the container on iOS:

```
.search .search-results.active {
  height: 100vh;
}
```